# How to add bootstrap to button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

This maybe a very silly question but oh well. I have never used Bootstrap before. I am using CodeIgniter for my website and I have added the Bootstrap files in the assest folder (where CodeIgniter file is). I want to add a Bootstrap CSS to this code

```
<button id="fight">Fight</button>
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

But i'm so clueless on how to do this....

I've added the Bootstrap link at top of my page and Jquery near the bottom but I don't know how to code the button for Bootstrap.

I wanted the "Fight" to be color red and "Run" to be color green.

I have already added those button IDs into my JavaScript file etc and don't want to mess around with it incase I mess something else up.

All the help and advice is appreciated, Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to use [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add the bootstrap class for buttons.

For red button (FIGHT):

```
<button id="fight" class="btn btn-danger">Fight</button>
```

(if you want it to be large or small just add btn-lg or btn-sm at the end of the class)

For green button (RUN):

```
<button id="run" class="btn btn-success">Run</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has many default button types, with varying colors. 
If you want to use the default colors, you can use the classes like this:

*Red button: 
        `<button id="fight" class="btn btn-danger">Fight</button>`

*Green button: 
        `<button id="run" class="btn btn-success">Run</button>`

If you want to know more, W3 Schools is a perfect place to practice the usage of Bootstrap: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to bootstrap, I would recommend going to their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) page. It shows a lot of examples for you to reference.

The way bootstrap works is it uses classes to apply its own pre-written css. In your example, you would want to add class="btn btn-danger" for red and class="btn btn-success" for green (refer to the docs). The btn class restyles the element to bootstrap's button (it alters padding, a default color, border, etc.). The btn-danger/btn-success are helper classes that change the background color of the button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div style="margin: 10px">
  No bootstrap
  <button id='fight'>Fight</button>
</div>

<div style="margin: 10px">
  Just class='btn'
  <button id='fight' class='btn'>Fight</button>
</div>


<div style="margin: 10px">
  Just class='btn-danger'
  <button id='fight' class='btn-danger'>Fight</button>
</div>

<div style="margin: 10px">
  Both class='btn btn-danger'
  <button id='fight' class='btn btn-danger'>Fight</button>
</div>
```